# How to add custom function to call after document.getElementById?

Tags: javascript, function

I'm just curious, how can I call a custom function after document.getElementById()? Something like this:

```
document.getElementById("element").mycustomfunction();
```

Comment: You **could** add a function to Element's prototype but you shouldn't. Why can't you simply pass the element as argument to your custom function ?

Comment: It depends on what `mycustomfunction()` is

Comment: @dystroy I can do that, and I know how, I'm just curious as to how I could do what asked.

Comment: @phpNoOb well just for an example, let's say that the function is "destroy()" and inside it just removes that element.

Comment: Element.prototype.mycustomfunction = function mycustomfunction() {};

Comment: Perhaps a developer of a library that is intended to be use publicly shouldn't extend native prototypes, but if this is for your project code, there's no problem in making the decision to enhance prototypes that way... as long as you're not supporting IE6/7, which will present a roadblock.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Technically you can do this :

```
Element.prototype.mycustomfunction = function() {
     console.log("I don't work on IE7");
};
```

You can test it easily in your console on this page : type it first and then `document.getElementById("notify-container").mycustomfunction();`.

It works. There's not technical problem with it. But it might make it a little harder for maintainers of your applications to trace what happens, it might led to collisions with other plugins doing the same, and it doesn't really add a lot over `myPlugin.doSomething(element)`.

Comment: And here are some reasons why that shouldn't be done: http://perfectionkills.com/whats-wrong-with-extending-the-dom/

Comment: @bfavaretto: That's a pretty old article, and mostly applies to IE6/7.

Comment: Thanks, for the answer, just for the sake of any future people viewing this page that don't want to go read an entire article, can you please list a few reasons why I **shouldn't** use this?

Comment: @squint Yes, but at least two reasons there still apply: (a) it's not future-proof (because of name collisions with future DOM extensions), and (b) "host objects have no rules", and can be unpredictable.

Comment: @Zachrip I added some. To be fair, as long as you know what you do, and you manage the whole application, it's not so big a problem. But that's a dangerous way to take, act with measure.

Comment: @bfavaretto: I'd hate to throw out an *extremely* useful technique just because *maybe* there'll be a name collision someday. IMO, the benefit far outweighs the risk. WRT "host objects have no rules", then you'd better not use jQuery, because it puts a property on many of the host objects it interacts with.

Comment: ...and host objects do have some rules defined in ES5, which I believe were absent from ES3.

Comment: Thanks guys, I think I'll use this information, this really helped. Surely I'm not the only one who wishes there were more consistencies between browsers :P

Comment: @squint I mostly agree with you, and I just posted that link as a sort of "standard warning" ( BTW, I upvoted this answer). I'm probably being too conservative, as many times I've been tempted to extend Element, and refrained to do so fearing it might go wrong at some point. You're making me rethink that, thanks.

Comment: @bfavaretto I reacted a little like you. We have our old reflexes, we know it's dangerous, but some of the old reasons disappeared (not all). What remains is that it's hard to manage a complex JavaScript application, so it's better to be cautious with anything that could make it harder to trace what happens and what component is responsible of what action.